# Convert String to Calender- Calender is the wrong date

Tags: java

trying to parse the String "2019-08-21 9:04:08" into a Calender object.

I am getting the result  Mon Dec 31 09:04:08 GMT 2018 from calender.getTime()

Here is how I parse it

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2019-08-21 9:04:08"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }// all done
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: A Calendar just keeps a Date which just keep a long ms. It has no inherent format, and delivers your local time to Greenwich Mean Time. So you evidently live on the 0 meridian, in England. Parsing from a format assumes a locale/clock. Also you need **HH** for 24 hours time.

Comment: Please see the docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html .

Comment: By the way, the newer time classes are a bit overwhelming but much better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the right parser format. The one you need is `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"`. The format `"YYYY"` is week-based calendar year, which is not what you want. As @rajah9 points out, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) can guide further regarding the use of `SimpleDateFormat`.